# Connect to backup sql server when main server is down (.net)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

what is the best how to handle this scenario:
I have 2 connection strings - Main, Backup. When connection to Main fails I would like to store data to BackUp server and once Main is ready again I would like to switch back (test connection to main in background once per 10min or so).

I'm fighting with try catch finally (or using clause) how to wrap it around these to connections trials and at the same time leave not to duplicate SQL command code.

Thanks

Edit: I would like to use SQL Express for backup server installed locally. This unease use of build in SQL technologies.

Comment: Connecting to the backup in the `CATCH` is risky since you are at that point assuming you will have no issues connecting there...

Answer (score 2):

You're probably putting a lot of effort into reinventing a wheel that already exists at the database level. Take a look at [high availability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190202.aspx) technologies such as [mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934127.aspx) and [failover clustering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Such scenario is handled automatically by so called "mirroring with witness".

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175191.aspx

Comment: +1 For expanding the horizons on the problem. I always tell my kids: if you want people to help you with something, tell people what you *need* done (your actual problem), not just ask how to do something you *think* is the solution for the problem.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it will require another (paid) SQL server. I would like to use SQL Express installed locally as backup.

Comment: @kurin123: I'm not a licensing expert, but I believe that you don't need to pay for another SQL license for DR purposes as long as you don't use it to serve active queries.  It's still hardware, OS, etc, but you don't need to license SQL.  This is true for mirroring and log shipping and I'd be surprised if it didn't also apply to replication.